# Como hacer una redireccion a otro sitio web en función del 'referrer'

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito hacer una redirección automática a otra página teniendo en cuenta el source del tráfico. Es decir, si el usuario proviene de x.com y aterriza en mi página, lo quiero redirigir a b.com, pero si el usuario proviene de z.com lo quiero redirigir a c.com

Para hacer el redirect utilizo esto:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">
```

Qué código puedo utilizar en el redirect para hacer una redirección u otra en función del source del tráfico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `document.referrer` y `window.location` puedes hacer el truco.

```js
if (document.referrer.indexOf("stackoverflow.com") != -1) {
  window.location = "http://southworks.com";
} else {
  window.location = "http://elotrositio.noexiste";
}
```

Comment: El problema es que necesito hacer una redirección en función de un referer y otra redirección distinta para todo lo que no tenga que ver con la url del referer. El código que has incluido me sirve para hacer una redirección en el caso de que el tráfico venga de un referer concreto, pero necesito que el resto del tráfico que no venga de ese referer url, vaya a otra página distinta.

Comment: Gracias! Entiendo que tengo que montar un servidor Apache para ejecutar esa función, verdad? Existe un código en HTML que haga lo mismo para evitar tener que montar el Apache? Muchas gracias.

Comment: @DavidMatas no, esto corre en el navegador... no importa el server. Si quieres hacerlo en el server es otra cosa diferente (muy diferente) ... te di esta respuesta pues pones un ejemplo en HTML y etiquetas la pregunta como javascript.

Comment: @DavidMatas osea que es parte de la pagina y no del server. se entiende?

Comment: Ya está, funciona perfecto. Mil gracias @rnd

Comment: @DavidMatas de nada, si te sirvió no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (marca en forma de V debajo de la puntuacion)

Comment: Hecho @rnd, por cierto si quiero añadir varias urls (referers distintos) para que apunten hacía una misma página concreta, puedo separarlas por coma todas ellas o tengo que hacer un código distinto?

Comment: @DavidMatas no, debers usar un operador logico OR `||`. Algo asi. `if (document.referrer.indexOf("stackoverflow.com") != -1 || document.referrer.indexOf("google.com") != -1) { ...`

Comment: Perdona que sea tan pesado, pero no me funciona ahora. He puesto esto <script>
if (document.referrer.indexOf("terra.com") != -1) || (document.referrer.indexOf("yahoo.com") != -1){
  window.location = "http://abc.com";
} else {
  window.location = "http://www.test.com/wp/";
}
</script>

Comment: @DavidMatas estan mal los parentesis, remplaza `) || (` por `||` unicamente, toda la condicion debe estar entre un par de parantesis. Osea que tamien serviria envolverla entre parentesis, pero hay muchos y no se va a entender bien.

Comment: Magnífico, ya funciona. Me ha sido de mucha utilidad. De nuevo, mil gracias. Un abrazo.

Comment: @DavidMatas suerte!!!